# how to include qutoes + double quotes in ng-regex?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, regex

I have phonegap application developed in android studio.

I have an input field that has to allow abc characters, quotes and double quotes.
wanted html code:

```
 <input placeholder="last name" type="text" ng-model="currentUser.LastName"
                       ng-pattern='/^([A-Za-z\"\' ]){1,45}$/'
                       required
                       class="form-control"/>
```

but I have a problem - the quotes in the regex close the whole regex.
what I can do:

```
ng-pattern='/^([A-Za-z\" ]){1,45}$/'
```

or

```
ng-pattern="/^([A-Za-z\' ]){1,45}$/"
```

but I cant find way to include quotes marks and double quotes, too.

I tried it:

in scope:

```
$scope.regex=/^([A-Za-z\"\' ]){1,45}$/;
```

in html page:

```
<input placeholder="last name" type="text" ng-model="currentUser.LastName" name="userLastName1"
                       ng-pattern='{{regex}}'
                       required
                       class="form-control"/>
```

it did not work, too (my editor is android studio, maybe other editors are better?).

is there any way to include both quotes and double quotes in one regex?

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) you don't need to interpolate the scope variable. You should be able to put it in your controller as `$scope.regex=/^([A-Za-z\"\' ]){1,45}$/;` and then use it in your template as `ng-pattern='regex'`

Comment: I have editted it just now, it was error in question, real code was right but it did not work.

Comment: What does `it did not work` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hex values for those entities, `\x22` for `"` and `\x27` for `'`:

```
$scope.regex= "/^[A-Za-z\x22\x27 ]{1,45}$/";
```

And you need no outer parentheses.

You can test it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

Or here is a snippet showing it works in an `ng-pattern` attribute:

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
  $scope.onSubmit = function(){
    alert("form submitted");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="formCtrl" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z\x22\x27 ]{1,45}$/" required placeholder="last name">
    <span ng-show="myForm.field.$error.pattern">Not valid!</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.field.$error.required">This field is required!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer. BTW, `ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z'\x22 ]{1,45}$/"` should also work (no need "obfuscating" the single apostrophe).